# Page.Validate vs Page.IsValid

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference between `Page.Validate` and `Page.IsValid`?

I read some articles about that

**Page.Validate** method is fired automatically by controls that have the CausesValidation property set to true(Which is default value for Button control).

**Page.IsValid** property tells you whether the validation succeeded or not.

But Which one is better? what was the relation between us?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/03/15/page-isvalid-and-validate.aspx

Comment: @GrantWinney , That's my question...

Answer (score 8):

[`Page.Validate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.validate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a method, [`Page.IsValid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a property. The former forces validation of one or all validation-groups (if no group is specified), the latter returns the result of this validation.

You don't need to call `Page.Validate` manually if the control that caused the postback has [`CausesValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  set to true(default).

Q: Why would you want to force validation on serverside at all or why would you want to set `CausesValidation` to `false`?

A: Sometimes you don't want to force validation on clientside always but only under certain conditions that are checked on serverside. Or you want to combine multiple validation-groups.